# Estrutura de repetição

Tags: java, loop

Estou estudando estrutura de repetição em Java aqui. E me deparei com a vontade de fazer o seguinte:

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
                System.out.println("Linha: " + j);
            }
            System.out.println(" Registro: " + i);
        }

    }
}
```

A saída desse trecho é:

```
Linha: 1
Linha: 2
    Registro: 1
Linha: 1
Linha: 2
   Registro: 2
```

E a saída desejada seria:

```
Linha: 1
Linha: 2
    Registro: 1
Linha: 3
Linha: 4
   Registro: 2
```

Ou seja, que no segundo giro do primeiro loop o j não fosse zerado, gerando assim *Linha 3 e Linha 4* para o segundo registro.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Só trocar o primeiro for pra `for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer dessa forma:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

    System.out.println("Linha: " + i);

    if(i%2==0){
        System.out.println(" Registro: " + (i/2));  
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/3gwhSD

---

Ou para ter controle do numero de registro e linhas de forma independente, basta fazer da forma abaixo:

```
int linhas = 3, 
registros = 2, 
temp = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= registros; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < linhas; j++){
        System.out.println("Linha: " + (temp++));
    }
        System.out.println(" Registro: " + i);
}
```

O resultado desse exemplo será:

```
Linha: 1
Linha: 2
Linha: 3
 Registro: 1
Linha: 4
Linha: 5
Linha: 6
 Registro: 2
```

Veja esse exemplo funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/3lkxOc

Comment: Putz, interessante! Vou aplicar alguns casos de uso aqui com valores variantes! Show :)

Comment: É. Tá bacana, mas quando quero editar o número de linhas  e/ou registros o operador módulo não dá certo.

Comment: @SamiVasconcelos ai você me complica hehe, eu fiz a solução baseado apenas no problema que você relatou na pergunta. Por isso a solução nem sempre pode atender a outros casos, mesmo que sejam parecidos :/

Comment: hahaaha.. faz parte! O negócio é desafiar! =)

Comment: @SamiVasconcelos por curiosidade, qual alteração que tentou fazer que não deu certo?

Comment: Se vc variar, por exemplo, o número de registros ele já desanda..

Comment: @SamiVasconcelos mas qual o novo padrão? Sem um padrao definido, é bem complicado pensar numa solução lógica. Na resposta, o padrao é 2 linhas  a cada registro. Se você mudar o laço para valores pares maiores(6,8,10...) verá que o padrão vai continua. se botar um valor impar, vai sobrar linha sem registro subsequente.

Comment: Então, pensando fora do padrão mesmo. Agora, assumo que o número de linhas e o número de registros é assumido por uma variável. Um valor inserido em tempo de execução.. complicou, né? Queimando a mufa aqui..

Comment: Posso assumir que cada registro terá 1000 linhas, por exemplo. Fechei o primeiro registro na linha 1000 e começo o novo registro da linha 1001 até 2001, por exemplo.

Comment: @SamiVasconcelos simples: https://ideone.com/3lkxOc Dessa forma, não importa o numero de linhas ou de registros, ambos ão independentes entre si, diferente do código da resposta.

Comment: Sim. Para o primeiro caso, tava ok. Com a mudança ele já não funciona. Mas, tranquilo! É assim mesmo.. a coisas sempre podem piorar.. Eu acho interessante pensar nessas variações.. tentando resolver aqui.

Comment: @SamiVasconcelos você viu o link que postei no comentario anterior? **https://ideone.com/3lkxOc** faça o teste variando com esse código desse link. Testei com variações até 50 e deu certo

Comment: Caraca, meu! Não tinha visto.. Qdo vejo essa simplicidade no código, percebo que estou loooonge de fica boa! hauahauaah Putz, mto fera!